# How can I delete image file when Image is removed from FlowDocument?

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit

I have an editable RichTextBox in which user can add tables, paragraphs, hyperlinks, images etc. When user inserts image, my program creates copy of picture from selected location to application's destined directory and sets this new source in Image object.

Now user can remove image from RichTextBox. In this case, the application should also remove image file from its directory. I tried to find any event that occurs in FlowDocument when any content is removed. There is no such event I found.

Alternatively I decided to use Unloaded event of Image object. When image is removed, Unloaded event is duly fired (twice sometimes) and my code to delete file works. Now problem is the RichTextBox is placed in a TabItem. If I shift to another tab item, Image object fires Unloaded event and file is deleted. To solve this problem, I tried to detect changes in properties of Image object during Unloaded event. I found I could use Parent property. Parent of Image object in FlowDocument is InlineUIContainer. So if image is removed, Parent of InlineUIContainer becomes null (not null when focus shifted to other TabItem). That gives me nod to delete image file, which works as desired.

But problem starts when image(s) fall in range of selection. In this case, Unloaded event is fired but Parent of InlineUIContainer is not null. I traced -

1. Image is in Paragraph, Parent of Paragraph becomes null,
2. Image is in TableCell, Parent of Table becomes null,
3. Image is in ListItem, Parent of List becomes null.

Image can be very deep in a tree. So checking parent of each container is tiresome.

Then I thought to grab XAML of selected content on Delete/Backspace key press. This way, I'll parse through Image tags that falls in selection using XML APIs and delete those files. I tried to write code to save selection of RichTextBox into a file. All selected elements, like Tables, List, Paragraph etc are available in resulted XAML, but Image is somehow omitted from the selection. I am writing following code.

```
var stream = new System.IO.FileStream("e:\\check.xml", System.IO.FileMode.Create);
rtfMain.Selection.Save(stream, DataFormats.Xaml, true);
stream.Close();
```

In summary, I just want to know if any content (Image, Hyperlink etc) is removed from FlowDocument and remove reference files. But somehow the solution seems very elusive.

Thank you for your time in advance.

Ritesh

Comment: Do you save these FlowDocuments to disk?

Comment: You save the FlowDocuments in the same directory as the images?  My thought is on save then place the FlowDocument and its images in its own directory and clear the working directory.